# Want to achieve maximum magnetic force & find out the max point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, forces, electric-fields, magnetic-fields

[image: setting]

Hi Sir/ Madam

Want to achieve maximum magnetic force & find out the max point for this setting, want to know

1. is the strongest magnetic force must in the 'dot' area ( middle poin of setting )
2. would the length of D1, D2, D3 affect the 'dot' location?
3. if add a metal sheet ( material AISI1010 ) between the magnet, would the magnetic force increase? would the thicknes of the sheet D4 affect the force?

Magnet material: NdFeB 52   5x10x18mm
D1 would be <4mm

Answer (score 1):

Since the arrangement is symmetrical when you interchange N and S, I would say that the maximum strength will come when D2 and D3 are equal. Also, the smaller D1 becomes, the more the flux lines will become compressed.

Also, a sheet of metal where you indicate would have almost the same effect as making the magnets wider, without an increase in mmf. So I suspect it will just weaken the field.

Generally, ferromagnetic materials and permanent magnets squeeze flux lines, while empty space causes them to spread out. The less volume you provide for spreading out, the more the lines will stay concentrated, increasing the flux.